# add many images in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

I want to put many more images in horizontal scroll view, please assume images as, a.jpeg, b.jpeg, c.jpeg, (d,e,f,g,h,i).jpeg and suggesst me to implemnt them in scrollview?

I tried to make by adding  many images  as shown below.

This method is lagging:

```java
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/a.jpeg"/>

<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/b.jpeg"/>

<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/c.jpeg"/>

and many other images....

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using your images directly without properly managing the memory that bitmaps take in Android.

When you directly use an image in `ImageView` using `android:src` tag, it's bound to lag if the images are too big.

Image loading libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) are used to load images by resizing the image depending on the `dpi` of the device.

In short: If you load a 1920*1080 image inside an `ImageView`, on a device directly, it'll load the complete image, i.e. full resolution image, wasting a lot of memory doing same, meaning, more stutter/lag while scrolling. But, when you load those same Images using image loading libraries, they'll resize the image, meaning, if the device is 1080p, your image is 4K resolution, and if your `ImageView` fills the screen (assuming that the image fits the device perfectly), this library will resize and make the image 1080p, and then put it inside the `ImageView`, saving a lot of memory needed to draw bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Add images dynamically

```
//int imageArray[] = [ R.drawable.ic_launcher, ....];

 HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) 
 findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
 for(int i=0; i< imageArray.length; i++) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    image.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[i]);
    horizontalScrollView.addView(image);
 }
```

Comment: I don't want dinamically, I want to allow user see images scrolling one after another, please @ArwyShelke  help me

Comment: as far i know, in this case there is no solution, you has to be compromise with your code. Its only 100 percent right in that way.

Comment: @Aarzu, I already told you the answer to your problem. At least read it instead of asking help to other people. At least read, go on the link that is mentioned. I came here after seeing my answer was upvoted once. What this person told is same as adding those ImageView through XML. If you use Image loading library as I told, it'll fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `RecycleView` instead of `HorizontalScrollView` to show dynamically your images.